# rand_r():Identifier is undefined , vs2008

Tags: c++, linux, thread-safety

when i use rand_r() in vs2008, it comes to 1 error--Identifier is undefined, can i use rand() instead ?   (multithread programming work.)
thanks.

Comment: One question per question please.

Comment: i will pay attention to this , anyway, thank you for this "warning" !

Comment: *knock knock*, care to accept an answer?

Answer (score 3):

You'd have to

```
#include <cstdlib>
```

In case you need this for multithreading purposes, see also Joachim Pileborgs answer.

In any case, maybe use one of [C++'s new RNGs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random), which you use in form of objects and that have guaranteed sequences.

---

[`man 3 rand_r`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/rand_r)

Comment: rand_r is POSIX (and obsolete), its not really guaranteed that VC has it too.

Comment: +1 for the C++11 RNGs. Solved my OpenMP performance problem (these RNGs are thread-local)

Answer (score 1):

According to [this forum thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/3263ab0b-da3f-4737-9d80-0788a5b426db) you should be able to use `rand` without needing to worry about reentrancy when using VC++.

Comment: Good reference, though he didn't mention that he need's this for multithreading.